# Is my Expectation for $Y = \frac{1}{1+ e^{aX}}$ for $X\sim\exp (1)$ correct?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, exponential-distribution

If $X\sim \exp(1)$, for $x \in \{0,+\infty \}$, and $Y = \frac{1}{1 + e^{aX} }$, where $a>0$ is a constant. (So the limit of Y becomes $y \in \{0, 1/2\}$) - **Is it correct**?

CDF $F_Y(y)$ of Y is :

$$F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)= \Big(\frac{1}{1 + e^{aX}} \leq y \Big)$$

after mathematical manipulations, I get

$$F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{(y-1)^{1/a}}$$

So the PDF is:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a}(y-1)^{-\frac{a-1}{a}}$$

The expected value of Y is now

$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^{1/2} y\times\frac{1}{a}(y-1)^{-\frac{a-1}{a}} dy $$

$$\mathbb{E} = \dfrac{a\left(2a\mathrm{e}^\frac{\ln\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{a}+\left(1-2a\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{\ln\left(-1\right)}{a}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{a}-\frac{\ln\left(-1\right)}{a}}}{2\left(a-1\right)}$$

Comment: You don't have to compute $F_Y$ if your ultimate goal is to find $E(Y)$. You can simply say $$E\bigg(\frac{1}{1+e^{aX}}\bigg)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f_{X}(x)}{1+e^{ax}}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{ax}}dx=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2(1+u^a)}$$  The last equality came from enforcing the substitution $u=e^x$.

Comment: $a>0$ is a positive constant. I have made the edit

Comment: Your final answer contains terms like $\ln(-1)$ and $\ln(-1/2)$ which have non$-$vanishing imaginary parts, which is suggesting your final answer is wrong. However, you are correct when you say that $Y$ is supported on $(0,1/2)$ since the image of $(0,\infty)$ under $y=\frac{1}{1+e^{ax}}$ is the open interval $(0,1/2)$.

Comment: (+1) I did not think of that. My actual expression (of which the above is just one part) cannot have imaginary value - It is an expression for a real-world system. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more direct to compute $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y] &= \operatorname{E}[(1+e^{aX})^{-1}] \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+e^{ax}} f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{ax}} \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} e^{-k a x} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-(ka+1) x} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{ka+1},
\end{align}$$ for $a > 0$.  If $a < 0$, then the series expansion is modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. It is pretty straight forward, I was going behind my head to touch my nose.

Comment: Can I please get the reference for $\sum^\infty_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}e^{-kax}$?  I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Since $$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k,$$ we have $$\frac{1}{1+z} = \frac{1/z}{1/z + 1} = \frac{1/z}{1 - (-1/z)} = \frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{-k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} z^{-k}.$$  Now let $z = e^{ax}$.